# Are the eigenvalues of Laplacian times Diagonal times Laplacian matrix non-negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Consider two (not identical) symmetric Laplacian matrices $L_1$ and $L_2$ and a diagonal matrix $D > 0$. My question is if the eigenvalues of the product $A =L_1 D L_2$ have non-negative real-part. It is well known that the product of two positive semi-definite matrices have eigenvalues with non-negative real part. (see e.g. the book by Bernstein: Matrix Mathematics, Theory, Facts, and Formulas). Extensive simulations show that $A$ has indeed eigenvalues with non-negative real part and that this not true in general if $L_1$ and $L_2$ were `only' positive semi-definite matrices. However, I have been, trying similarity transformations and Sylvester's law of inertia, unable to find a proof. Of course, a counterexample would be very useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. A random counterexample: the eigenvalues of
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0&-1\\ 0&1&-1\\ -1&-1&2}
\pmatrix{1\\ &3\\ &&1}
\pmatrix{2&-1&-1\\ -1&1&0\\ -1&0&1}
=\pmatrix{3&-1&-2\\ -2&3&-1\\ -1&-2&3}
$$
are $0$ and $\frac12(9\pm i\sqrt{3})$, so $A$ has non-real eigenvalues. When the matrix sizes are larger (such as $5\times5$), we can even obtain easily a counterexample in which $A$ has a negative real eigenvalue.

**Edit.** Another counterexample: the matrix product
\begin{align*}
A&=\pmatrix{
 1& 0& 0&-1& 0\\
 0& 2&-1& 0&-1\\
 0&-1& 2& 0&-1\\
-1& 0& 0& 1& 0\\
 0&-1&-1& 0& 2}
\pmatrix{1\\ &3\\ &&3\\ &&&3\\ &&&&3}
\pmatrix{
 2&-1& 0& 0&-1\\
-1& 2& 0& 0&-1\\
 0& 0& 1&-1& 0\\
 0& 0&-1& 1& 0\\
-1&-1& 0& 0& 2}\\
&=\pmatrix{
 2&-1& 3&-3&-1\\
-3&15&-3& 3&-12\\
 6&-3& 6&-6&-3\\
-2& 1&-3& 3& 1\\
-3&-12&-3& 3&15},
\end{align*}
has an eigenpair $(\lambda,v)$ where $\lambda\approx-0.2111<0$ and $v\approx(0.46902,\,0.30552,\,-0.61103,\,-0.46902,\,0.30552)^T$.

Comment: Thank you. I clarified my question that I meant with non-negative, non-negative real part. Can you provide an example where $A$ has a negative real eigenvalue? You mention that it is easy, but unfortunately I do not find one.

Comment: @galirt Not meant to be rude, but for 5-by-5 matrices, it is indeed easy to obtain a counterexample with a real negative eigenvalue. There may be some limitations in the simulations you've done.

Comment: Thanks. I have rerun my simulations, and I find indeed examples when the Laplacians (at least one) do not correspond to connected graphs (like your example). Initially, I excluded this possibility in my simulations as my associated graphs are always connected. Do you think this absence of connectivity is essential to find a counterexample?

Comment: @galirt It's quite plausible. I cannot obtain a counterexample (for matrices with sizes $\le8$) with a connected graph too.